# Jmeter - Difference between thread group and loop controller in terms of performance

Tags: jmeter

I am new to Jmeter. Here is one thing that is puzzling me

There are two scenarios that I am testing to calculate performance numbers using Jmeter

1. Having a 1 thread group set with loop count set to 50 and having one https sampler.
2. Having a 1 thread group with loop count as only 1 but instead using a loop controller having loop count set to 50. In this case my https sampler is inside the loop count.

In both cases the https sampler is run 50 times but I am noticing a lot of performance difference.

```
For 1 - 100 ms ( Average of 50 calls)
For 2 - 30 ms ( Average of 50 calls)
```

Question is why am I seeing this difference. Ideally both scenario should give the same performance number.
Also to add in my Jmeter setting I have  "Use keep alive" as off and also https.use.cached.ssl.context is set to false in jmeter.properties.

Answer (score 0):

What is your `Ramp-up` setting for scenario where 50 loops are defined on Thread Group level? As per [documentation](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html)

> The ramp-up period tells JMeter how long to take to "ramp-up" to the full number of threads chosen. If 10 threads are used, and the ramp-up period is 100 seconds, then JMeter will take 100 seconds to get all 10 threads up and running. Each thread will start 10 (100/10) seconds after the previous thread was begun. If there are 30 threads and a ramp-up period of 120 seconds, then each successive thread will be delayed by 4 seconds

By default ramp-up is `1`. If you're looking for the same behavior for Thread Group and Loop Controller you need to set it to `0`.

Going forward, sending requests as fast as JMeter can is not something that could be called a real-life load scenario. Real users aren't hammering this or that endpoint, they need some time to "think" before doing next action. This "think time" can be simulated using i.e. [Constant Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Timer). However the smarter way to set the desired load is using [Constant Throughput Timer](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer)

Comment: iteration and loop control are used after threads are initialized. what you are saying is before starting threads. I think user1788294 is using only 1 user/thread and is aware of rampup. IMHO what you are saying is bit off topic here.please correct if I am wrong.

Comment: that correct. I am using only 1 user/thread . I suspect that it is DNS caching which is causing this performance difference.